# Role of PDF of Uniform Random Sampling in a path tracer

Tags: c++, random, raytracing

I am trying to implement my own path tracer but before arriving to the question I want to give you a short overview:
In the implementation of the rendering equation I use some particular technique in order to sample surfaces. For example: when one of my rays hits a diffuse surface, the next ray bouncing from that surface will be calculated using a *Cosine-weighted Random Direction*. This implies that in my rendering equation I have to take into account the PDF that this specific random distribution implies and specifically divide for this PDF in my equation. So far everything is okey.

Now, my question. I want to implement a particular technique called "next event estimation" which simply samples the lights. In order to do so, I want to pick a **random point** on my light, which is spherical, by using the following code (C++):

```
Vec3<float> randomPoint() const
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

        // random vector in unit sphere
    do
    {
        x = ((float)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1;           // random coordinates between -1 and 1
        y = ((float)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1;
        z = ((float)rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1;
    } while (pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2) > 1);        // simple rejection sampling

    return centerOfSphere + Vec3<float>(x, y, z) * radius;
}
```

As far as I understand (please correct me if wrong), this implements a **uniformly random sampling**. Also, as far as I have read, this kind of sampling has a PDF = 1 / (b - a) . My question: do I have to use this PDF as well like I do for my *Cosine-weighted Random Distribution* or not, since it is a uniform distribution? if yes, what's the range (b - a) that PDF talks about? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you define more precisely what  the cosine-weighted random distribution is? Please note that your random point (x,y,z) takes value in the unit ball only if you consider the infinite norm

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does PDF mean in this context? I tried googling it but just wound up finding a lot of PDF files about ray tracing.

Comment: @Rerito the cosine-weigthed method is used to pick a point on a hemisphere, in my case it is cosine weighted with respect to the normal of that hemisphere. Page 19 and 20 of https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~philip.dutre/GI/TotalCompendium.pdf
But.. what do you mean that it takes value only if I consider the infinite normal? don't get it sorry

Comment: @Ferruccio the PDF is the "probability density function"